# C passing terminal commands and print answer

Tags: c, variables, terminal

I am trying to execute a command in terminal and analyze the result, but i can´t get the output written in the variable.
I have made an example code that shows my problem:

```
extern char commandResult;

int main()
{
   char commandResult;
   commandResult = system("[ -f /etc/hosts ] && echo "Found" || echo "Not found"");
   printf("result: ");
   printf("%s", commandResult);
   printf("\n");
}
```

but the output is like this:

```
CMakeCache.txt      Makefile        logo.c
CMakeFiles          pitm            pitm.c
CMakeLists.txt      README.md
LICENSE             cmake_install.cmake
result: (null) <- The output is supposed to be here! :/
```

I am going to analyze the variable with a "switch/case" or if/else block like

```
if(commandResult == "Found") {
    printf("Yes");
} else {
    printf("No");
}
```

So can anyone tell me how to get the output to me written to the variable and not directly outputted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`system` doesn't return the output the *command* you run but simply returns the exit status. You probably want to use [popen()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/popen.html) to read the output of the command you run. See an example in the linked man page.

You also need to use [strcmp](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html) for comparing strings, not `==`.